# Why are my Touch Bar volume controls grayed out (disabled)?

Tags: sound-volume, touch-bar

I’m unable to adjust the volume using my Touch Bar, how do I get out of this mode?

[image]

**(as you can see the volume buttons are disabled).**

Comment: Try going to Sound System Preference and see if you can drag the volume slider and change the volume there?

Comment: Those are not volume up down buttons those are sound ON/OFF buttons. Unfortunately I have no clue as to why they are greyed out

Comment: Is your computer plugged into a monitor or do you have any kind of audio devices connected? Would be helpful to see your current sound output and if you’re available to adjust there (as Nimesh mentioned).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. The fix:

- Open System Preferences > Sound
- Select the *Output* tab
- Select *MacBook Pro Speakers* (or another working output) under *Select a device for sound output*.

The cause: I connected my MBP to an external monitor, which, unbeknownst to me, had speakers of its own.